pyqtgraph: LegendItem offset returns false values regardless of position
I have a Qt5 window with a pyqtgraph in a dynamic situation, i.e., plots, axes, curves can be added or modified. Also, the legend can be shown and hidden. Since the user can also drag the legend to a different place using the mouse, I would like to store its position and perhaps restore this position later. Setting a position using LegendItems' setOffset works as expected, but regardless of the actual position, LegendItems' offset attribute always returns the same values. Here's a MWE:
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

win = pg.plot()
win.setWindowTitle('MWE legend offset')

c1 = win.plot([np.random.randint(0,8) for i in range(10)], pen='r', name='curve1')

legend = pg.LegendItem((80,60), offset=(70,20))
legend.setParentItem(win.graphicsItem())
legend.addItem(c1, 'curve1')

print(f"Before setting an offset: {legend.offset}") # Gives (70,20)
legend.setOffset([300,300])
print(f"After setting an offset: {legend.offset}") # Gives (70,20) as well

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.exec()

Any idea how to get the real LegendItem position?

Replacing legend.offset by legend.opts['offset'] does work.
I think that the devs forgot to update legend.offset in the setOffset() method.
